# Expression language to SQL where clause transformations?

Tags: java, sql, parsing

We have one domain object,

```
Person
    firstName
    lastName
    role
```

I'm looking for a simple expression language that we can write that will generate SQL.  (particulary the where clause of SQL)

For example.

```
firstName contains "joe"
```

translates to

```
FIRST_NAME LIKE '%joe%'
```

Does anything like this exist, or do I have to write my own?

Please let me know if you think I might as well be searching for the fountain of youth, or if you think i'm wasting my time writing this!

Comment: It's unclear why you want to translate from some unspecified expression language that looks sort of like SQL into SQL. Why not just use SQL? (BTW: there's some sort of typo in your first sentence after your first example that renders it unparsable.)

Comment: Tragically, we want non techi folks to write it the expressions.  I know it's an awkward question.

Comment: What makes you think your "new expression langauge" would be any more familiar to your non-techy folks than SQL?

Comment: The domain is small, the operators are limited.  Otherwise no guarantee, but our designers are adamant :).

Comment: Why don't you pick out the subset of SQL that matches your "limited operators"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "However, there is also a large class
> of users who, while they are not
> computer specialists, would be willing
> to learn to interact with a computer
> in a reasonably high-level,
> non-procedural query language. Examples
> of such users are accountants,
> engineers, architects, and urban
> planners."

That's from Donald D. Chamberlin and Raymond F. Boyce's [1974 paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20181122134941/http://www.almaden.ibm.com/cs/people/chamberlin/sequel-1974.pdf) introducing SQL (then SEQUEL). From their introduction, I'd guess they designed SQL for your non-technical users.

That's not to say SQL is a perfect language. Despite thirty-some years of changes, it still has flaws. There's a chance you could build something better, but two things could go wrong:

1. Your language could be worse.
2. If one of your non-technical users wanted to beef up their relational data skills, they would be limited by your language versus SQL. There are many, many resources to improve SQL skills and far fewer ways to improve skills in a new language.

Maybe consider a compromise: offer an expression-building UI. Less technical users could choose a property, an operator, and enter values which would then appear in an expression text area. They could build moderately complex SQL expressions piece-by-piece without needing to remember SQL syntax. More sophisticated users could edit the SQL directly.

This doesn't solve all of your problems. You'll still need a way to limit SQL so users don't damage your database or inadvertently use up all of your db resources with a mind-boggling Cartesian join.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into the [Selection Factory](http://www.diranieh.com/DataAccessPatterns/SelectionFactory.htm) pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I like that.  I might be able to use this but I'm also going to keep looking for a away to build complex AND OR logic.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know whether that suffices, but there is an example of the xtext project (a language development framework) for an entity language like that (the domain model). maybe you want to check that out. it also features code generation for jpa (as far as i remember). if it's not cool, just write your own language, shouldn't take too long using xtext ;)